# How do I properly enqueue javascript with jQuery dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a simple javascript file named `br-tagging.js` that I am trying to enqueue in Wordpress. All that it does is add an onclick function to a button that alerts "Hello World!". The js file is located in the child theme's root directory. The javascript file and corresponding HTML for the button are as follows:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="br-button">
    Test Button
</button>
```

**JS - (br-tagging.js)**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#br-button").click(function() {
        alert("Hello World");
    });
});
```

I have created the following function in my child theme's `functions.php` file:

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'br_enqueue');
function br_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('br-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/br-tagging.js', array('jQuery'));
}
```

It doesn't seem that the javascript file is being enqueued into Wordpress. I can't find the file anywhere in the header of the page. The button doesn't work when I click it.

The strange thing is that if I take out the jQuery dependency in `wp_enqueue_script` like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'br_enqueue');
function br_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('br-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/br-tagging.js');
}
```

Then I end up with an exception being returned stating that `$` is not defined (as you would expect if JQuery isn't being included as a dependency). But when I put it back in, there is no error, just the button doesn't work and the script isn't found in the header.

[image]

Any idea what is happening? I feel like I must be missing something very simple. I am not very experienced with Wordpress, so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Thank you.

Comment: jquery needs to be lower case: `wp_enqueue_script('br-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/br-tagging.js', array('jquery'));`. Also, try and setting the `in_footer` argument to true. `wp_enqueue_script('br-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/br-tagging.js', array('jquery'), '', true);`

Comment: I see that in the documentation now, but that just brings back the `$ is not defined` problem.

Comment: try wrapping your JS in `(function($) { your code })(jQuery);`

Comment: Just found this on my own after fixing the case sensitive issue for `jquery`. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer on my own after being shown that the `jQuery` needed to be all lowercase `jquery` in the dependencies argument of the `wp_enqueue_script` function. It turns out that the WP-supplied jQuery is put in no-conflict, causing this issue. The fix is to wrap your jQuery code in `(function($) { //code here })(jQuery);` to get it to work.

For clarity... the final code looked like this:

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'br_enqueue');
function br_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script('br-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/br-tagging.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
}
```

**JS - br-tagging.js**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#br-button").click(function() {
            alert("Hello World");
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

After doing this it all worked fine!

Comment: Note that this may not work if inside `br-tagging.js` you have defined functions that depend on `jQuery` but have not themselves imported it. In such a case, instead of wrapping the contents of `br-tagging.js` in an anonymous function, define `$` by placing `let $ = jQuery` at the top of that script.